# Django Apache and WSGI setup not finding urls?

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi, wsgi, django-wsgi

I am setting up Django on a VPS with Apache and and modwsgi and have this setup for 000-default.conf,

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
. . .

Alias /static /home/user/myproject/static
<Directory /home/user/myproject/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/user/myproject/myproject>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess myproject python-path=/home/user/myproject 
WSGIProcessGroup myproject
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py
```

but when I access my www.myproject.com I get this error

```
Not Found
```

The requested URL / was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at www.myproject.com Port 80

What could be wrong?

Comment: Python path should be like this: python-path=/home/user/myproject:path/to/python/site-packages

Comment: You should use ``python-home`` for specifying the location of the Python virtual environment, not passing ``site-packages`` to ``python-path``. See http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html